# MediaWiki - Using the Widgets widget - I cannot get it to 'parse' my page

Tags: javascript, php, widget, mediawiki

Ok so I have, I think followed the steps here correctly:
http://www.mediawikiwidgets.org/AdSense

I created a page www.mysite/wiki/Widget:AdSense
and added the following: (with my details)

```
{{#widget:AdSense
|name=myadname
|client=ca-pub-4602712147397250
|slot=6127367636
|width = 160
|height = 600
}}
```

Then in my Wiki Home page (Main_Page) I added the following to where I wish the ads to display

```
{{Widget:AdSense}}
```

Both pages display:

```
{{#widget:AdSense|name=myadname|client=ca-pub-4602712147397250|slot=6127367636|width = 160|height       = 600}}
```

What am I doing wrong? Do you need more info?